# Aspose.Words IFieldMergingCallback access data source object

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.words

I'm writing a IFieldMergingCallback class for Aspose.Words and in the FieldMerging would like to access the current row of the current table that has triggered the call to the method... I can see a way to get the value of the specific field, but no way to get further data?

Answer (score 1):

Please check following code snippet for your kind reference. Hope this helps you.

```
void IFieldMergingCallback.FieldMerging(FieldMergingArgs args)
{
    Row row = (Row)args.Field.Start.GetAncestor(NodeType.Row);
    if (row != null)
    {
        //Your code...
    }
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: Thanks but i think you miss understood the question, I want to get access to the System.Data.DataRow its using for the merge at that moment in time

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no API to get the underlying Data Source during a mail merge process. Please post your requirements in [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.